# Issue with converting numerical values to string elements

Tags: c++

So as the title implies I am having an issue with my algorithm used to convert numerical values to strings.  I can get up to a certain amount but then the program crashes once I hit 100 dollars.  I'm also off by a couple cents on some values so I'm wondering what I could do to change that as well.

Here is my header file

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class TextVersionOfNumber
{
private:
    double amount;
public:
    string getTextVersionOfNumber();
    void setAmount(double);
};
```

Here is my .cpp file (this is where the algorithm is)

```
#include "TextVersionOfNumber.h"


string TextVersionOfNumber::getTextVersionOfNumber()
{
    string upto20[20] = { "", "one", "two", "three", "four",
        "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
        "eleven", "twelve",
        "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen",
        "eighteen", "nineteen" };

    string ten_ninety[10] = { "", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty",
        "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

    double _amount1 = (int)amount;
    double _amount2 = (amount - _amount1) * 100;

    string str_one = "";

    if (_amount1 <= 19)
    {
        str_one = upto20[(int)_amount1];
    }
    else
    {
        int tens = _amount1 / 10;
        int ones = _amount1 - (tens * 10);
        str_one = ten_ninety[tens] + upto20[ones];
    }

    string str_two = "";

    if (_amount2 <= 19)
    {
        str_two = upto20[(int)_amount2];
    }
    else
    {
        int tens = _amount2 / 10;
        int ones = _amount2 - (tens * 10);
        str_two = ten_ninety[tens] + upto20[ones];
    }

    string ret_val = "$ " +str_one + " and " + str_two + " cents";
    system("pause");
    return ret_val;
};



void TextVersionOfNumber::setAmount(double _amount)
{
    amount = _amount;
};
```

And here is the tester file (this was provided by my teacher)

```
//  Chapter 12--  Assignment 14:  Check Writer
// This program can convert a dollar and cents amount given in 
// numerical form to a word description of the amount.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

#include "TextVersionOfNumber.h"
// Assume a maximum amount of $10,000

int main()
{
    string date = "03/05/2016", payee = "Michael Wille";
    TextVersionOfNumber checkAmount;
    double testAmounts[] = { 0, .01, .25, 12, 12.45, 19, 19.02,
        19.45, 20, 20.45,
        34, 56.78, 100, 109, 119.78,
        450, 678.90, 1000, 1009.45, 1056,
        1234, 1567.98, 9999, 9999.99 };

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(testAmounts) / sizeof(double); i++)
    {
        double an_amount = testAmounts[i];
        checkAmount.setAmount(an_amount);
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
        cout << setw(60) << right;
        cout << "Date: " << date << endl;
        cout << "Pay to the order of:  " << payee << "\t\t\t";
        cout << "$" << an_amount << endl;
        cout << checkAmount.getTextVersionOfNumber() << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I know part of the issue is within my ten_ninety array but everything I've tried hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: When amount is 100, then `tens` will be 10, your `ten_ninety` array size is 10 and you are accessing one element past your array when you say `ten_ninety[tens]` since the range is 0 to arraysize-1 which would be 9.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: 1) doubles are not exact. 2) why would you code something like this by hand when the standard library contains pre-made functions to convert between strings and integer/floating point and vice versa...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  else
    {
        int tens = _amount1 / 10;
        int ones = _amount1 - (tens * 10);
        str_one = ten_ninety[tens] + upto20[ones];
    }
```

if amount = 100, then tens will equal 10, which you use as reference into an array of 10 elements, which steps outside the bounds of the array. You code might work < 100, but once it hits a hundred it won't function anymore.

Comment: Would you recommend I create int hundreds or is there another approach to this that I'm overlooking?  (I'm not asking for answers, just looking to be steered in the right direction)

Comment: @MichaelWille I would start with the one's digit (amount % 10) and work up the value from there.